# Make file: Flow doesnt enter if loop

Tags: c, linux, makefile, proc

i am trying to compile huge number of files (.pc pro*c code, c code and .h files into an exe) into one exe.

Sample code.

Please note that, the tab characters are placed accordingly. However removed here while posting.

Sorry, tried to fix the indentation.. however will do it better now.

**Please note that, T at the beginning of the line would represent a Tab character.**

```
build :$(OBJS)

T @if [ "$(EXE)" = "abc" ]; then \

T echodo  `command`\

T elif [ "$(ORA_CLIENT_LIB)" = "shared" ]; then \

T echodo $(CC) $(LDFLAGSSHRD) $(LIBPATHS)  -m64 -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) `cat $(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib/sysliblist ` $(LIBHOME)/libclntsh.so; \

T else \

T echodo $(CC) $(LIBPATH) -m64 -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) -L$(LIBPATH) $(PROLDLIB) $(AMOLIB) $(LIBHOME)/libclntsh. a ;\

T fi
```

The variable ORA CLient Lib is set to shared. and still, the code doesnt enter the elif block. Am i missing anything?

When I run the make, I am getting the error...

```
------/bin/sh: -c: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
------make: *** [build] Error 2
```

All the .o files got created however the exe is not. I dont understand what's missing. 
echodo is a file of Oracle bin. As i am compiling ProC code, so it must have some relevance.

Comment: Is that a Makefile part? You *really* need to fix the indent/formatting, it's unreadable as-is.

Comment: Fixed the indentation sir.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and venture a guess...

I'm guessing that `echodo` echoes all its arguments, and executes the first argument as a command, with the remaining arguments as arguments to the command it executes.

However in the line

```
echodo  --------
```

It echoes `--------` and *then tries to execute it*. And as it's unlikely that you have a command named `--------` you will get an error.

If you want to echo the string `--------`, then use the normal plain `echo` command.

Comment: I had to strip some code from posting here because of security reasons. The '\' is used at the end of lines. Even i didnt get what Echodo is, however it is being used in the existing files. I see that it is a file present in oracle bin folder. So it must be a file related to Pro*C

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting to see `\`s on all of the lines except the last like this:

```
build: $(OBJS)
        @if [ "$(EXE)" = "abc" ]; then \
        echo --------; \
        elif [ "$(ORA_CLIENT_LIB)" = "shared" ]; then \
        echodo $(CC) $(LDFLAGSSHRD) $(LIBPATHS)  -m64 -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) `cat $(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib/sysliblist ` $(LIBHOME)/libclntsh.so; \
        else \
        echodo $(CC) $(LIBPATH) -m64 -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) -L$(LIBPATH) $(PROLDLIB) $(AMOLIB) $(LIBHOME)/libclntsh.a; \
        fi
```